# What is the best way to post an image to a server using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I want the user to post an image to the server and load it back into the page when its ready, all this without leaving the page. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend the [jQuery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).  It has support for file uploads and after completion, you could display the image back to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Post to and display the image in an IFrame.

Here is some more detail: http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/